# Framer Motion Library "hooks" not working with reagent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, reagent, framer-motion

The path tag of framer motion can be used in conjunction with useViewportScroll to create a scroll info path.

```
const { scrollYProgress } = useViewportScroll()

return (
  <motion.path style={{ pathLength: scrollYProgress }} />
)
```

When used with Clojurescript, this doesn't work:

```
(def div (.-div motion))
(def path (.-path motion))

(defn my-component []
    [:> div 
       [:> path {:style {:pathLength (.-scrollYProgress (useViewportScroll))}}]]

)
```

The error is:

```
Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See  for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

-- EDIT --

Based on an answer, I changed to this:

```
(defn path []
  (let [path (.-path motion)
        path-length (.-scrollYProgress (useViewportScroll))]
    (r/as-element
     (do
       (js/console.log "path length is " path-length)
       [:> path {:style {:pathLength path-length}}]
       ))))
```

and use `[:> path]` in my-component. But the console log isn't triggered when I scroll the page, suggesting that the path-length variable isn't changing when scroll, i.e., the path component isn't remounted with the scroll. How to fix this?

Comment: How are you using the `path` component?

Comment: If you can answer this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62545637/lastcallbacknode-is-not-a-function
It solves everything.

Answer (score 0):

Hiccup style components won't work with Hooks, because in order to interpret the returned hiccup, Reagent creates a class component, not a functional component (Frankly this is probably a historical oddity as Reagent pre-dates the hooks API).

Instead you need to create a functional component by passing `reagent.core/create-element` a function, but in that function you either will have to create React DOM elements by hand, or convert the hiccup yourself. See: https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/master/doc/ReactFeatures.md#function-components